# imagem move quando sobe ou desce o scrool

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho uma imagem dentro de uma tabela. Quero que essa imagem move quando se desce ou sobe com o scoll. Ja utilisei o position fixed.

O meu exemplo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3n4Df/88/

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico? Como assim "se mova"? Ela está se movendo, para baixo e para cima. Além disso, poderia adicionar o código à pergunta, vai que amanhã os servidores do JSFiddle deixem de funcionar...

Comment: Mas quero que a imagem acompanhe sempre o scroll

Comment: Mas em um tabela? Ela sempre terá o rowspan?

Comment: Pois o meu problema é mesmo a tabela. Queria que fosse dentro da tabela como esta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isto utilizando o position: fixed e especificar um valor para o alinhamento sendo,top,left,right e bottom...

Depois Adicione um js (jQuery para que a div acompanhe o scroll).

Detalhe, você deve especificar o tamanho da sua div por que pode ocorrer da imagem estar passando por cima de conteúdo ficando uma ma experiência para o usuario.

### Exemplo:

```js
$('#divDaImg').scroll(function() {
  $('#FixedDiv').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
.img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem
    Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente
    quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>

</div>
<div id="divDaImg">
  <img src='https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdw26b_dwa8moS-gRSFpaG3dwJTB6Nqtqxexmb7PscuD5gVP-P' width=90 class="img" />
</div>
```

Comment: Como posso fazer no meu exemplo dentro de uma tabela e sem jquery?